# Membership - get user email

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using ASP.Net MVC2 with the default membership/profile/role providers, I'd like to access the user email in my ForgotPassword Action to email a new password to the user, but so far I've only been able to get the username (User.Identity.Name).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access user information in MembershipUser class using Membership class, f.ex:

```
...
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(username);
//u.Email - this is user's email
...
```